# Git Bash error: open failed: administratively prohibited

Tags: ssh, git-bash

I'm using Git Bash that comes with Git for Windows and running this command:

ssh -J user@jumpserver root@vmserver

and getting this error:

channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Searching this error gets a lot of results where the resolution was to modify a couple options in the /etc/sshd_config file and restarting the ssh service.

I tried simply creating the sshd_config file in Git Bash since it seems to have its own file system thing going on... Don't know if that's correct or if I just need to figure out how to restart the ssh service. Windows doesn't list any ssh service that I can see. I also tried creating a sshd_config file in my .ssh folder.

Can anyone help with this?

An additional side question - Git Bash is asking for my password to my rsa key each time, but both hosts I am connecting through do not use public key authentication, just basic passwords. Is there a way to not have to enter the rsa key password since it is not needed?

Comment: 1. I think you problem on vmserver side, where you should change sshd_config file 2. When you creating key-pai you should leave this question empty - Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):  - to not promt it each time

Comment: On vmserver I set /etc/sshd_config to:

PermitOpen=any
AllowTCPForwarding=yes
PermitTunnel=yes

and then ran "service sshd restart" and am still experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... the problem is simply that the hostname vmserver wasn't defined on the jumpserver. I didn't realize it would resolve the hostname context from the jumpserver and not my local machine.